# How to put an onboarding screen on the screen even though the navigation controler is the rootView

Tags: swift, swift3

I am making an app that includes an onboarding screen inn swift. In the AppDelegate.swift I set the navigationController as the root view controller. But I have an onboarding screen and need to add that to the code also. Whenever I run the app I get `Thread 1: SIGNAL SIBAGRT`. Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [ . 
UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


  let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    let controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! AllListsViewController
    controller.dataModel = dataModel
```

Comment: is the your storyboard is `Main` or `Onboarding` or is it the id of the navigationController ?

Comment: @Lamar `Onboarding`

Comment: ok I added an answer try it let me know it goes

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(named:"Onboarding",bundle: nil)
let nvc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UINavigationController // since your storyboard start with a navigationController 
let topVc = nvc.topViewController as? AllListsViewController // then we get the first controller associated to that navigationController 
topVc?.dataModel = dataModel 
window?.rootViewController = nvc // still set your navigationController as the root of your application 
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the crash @KrishMehra